# MySql select multiple columns when has value

Tags: mysql

I need to select some columns from a table and also some other columns depending on a value from one column. For example:

```
 SELECT 
    col_a, col_b, col_c
FROM user_table 

INNER JOIN col_d, col_e, col_f ON col_type = 1
INNER JOIN col_g, col_h, col_i ON col_type = 2

WHERE id = :id
AND active = 1
```

Since I'm new to mysql, I don't how how i should do this. I tried using `CASE WHEN` but was able to select a single column and I need to select multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunterstood INNER JOIN and you want something like that

```
SELECT 
    col_a, col_b, col_c,
    IF( col_type = 1, col_d, NULL ) AS col_d,
    IF( col_type = 1, col_e, NULL ) AS col_e,
    IF( col_type = 2, col_g, NULL ) AS col_g,
    IF( col_type = 2, col_h, NULL ) AS col_h
FROM user_table 

WHERE id = :id
AND active = 1
```

But i prefere to load all cols and handle it with your other language (PHP?).

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid, because if I have 20 columns to select, I need to do the if 20 times just for one case (and yes, PHP in the backend).

Comment: Then is PHP the way to go. You can build there very comfortable and flexible functions to load your entry like this.